# Jenkins Docker Container can't access docker.sock in GKE Autopilot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have installed Jenkins using helm v3 in GKE Autopilot Clustor using default [chart value](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/values.yaml). I am trying to create a Docker image from Jenkins but getting permission issue (*autogke-no-write-mode-hostpath*).

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nodejs
            image: node:16
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "4Gi"
                cpu: "1000m"
          - name: gcloud-sdk
            image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: docker
            image: docker:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
              name: docker-sock
          volumes:
            - name: docker-sock
              hostPath:
                path: /var/run/docker.sock
        '''
    }
  }
    environment {
        // GKE
        PROJECT_ID = 'example-0000'

        // Docker
        GCR_HOSTNAME = 'us.gcr.io'
        DOCKER_IMG = "${env.GCR_HOSTNAME}/${env.PROJECT_ID}/my-app"
        DOCKER_IMG_TAG = "${env.DOCKER_IMG}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

        NODE_ENV = 'production'

        HOME = "${WORKSPACE}"
        NPM_CONFIG_CACHE = "${WORKSPACE}/.npm"
    }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build: Docker Image') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'sandbox' }
            }
            steps {
                container('docker') {
                    sh "sed -i 's#__NODE_ENV__#${NODE_ENV}#' ./Dockerfile"

                    sh "docker build -t ${env.DOCKER_IMG_TAG} ."

                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'my-gcr-cred', variable: 'GCR_MANAGER_KEY')]) {
                        sh 'chmod 600 $GCR_MANAGER_KEY'
                        sh('cat $GCR_MANAGER_KEY | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://' + "${env.GCR_HOSTNAME}")
                        sh "docker push ${DOCKER_IMG_TAG}"
                        sh "docker logout https://${env.GCR_HOSTNAME}"
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                always {
                    sh "docker rmi ${env.DOCKER_IMG_TAG}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error that I am getting

> ERROR: Unable to create pod kubernetes jenkins/pro-7-bmvlz-n2z9s-bqxmd.
> Failure executing: POST at: https://10.100.108.3/api/v1/namespaces/jenkins/pods. Message: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-no-write-mode-hostpath]":["hostPath volume docker-sock in container docker is accessed in write mode; disallowed in Autopilot. Requested by user: 'system:serviceaccount:jenkins:jenkinsv2', groups: 'system:serviceaccounts,system:serviceaccounts:jenkins,system:authenticated'."]}. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=400, details=null, kind=Status, message=admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-no-write-mode-hostpath]":["hostPath volume docker-sock in container docker is accessed in write mode; disallowed in Autopilot. Requested by user: 'system:serviceaccount:jenkins:jenkinsv2', groups: 'system:serviceaccounts,system:serviceaccounts:jenkins,system:authenticated'."]}, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=[denied by autogke-no-write-mode-hostpath], status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker and Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but related to policies in kubernetes/GKE, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to access is at the /var/run and Docker in Jenkin

However, if we see GKE auto pilot is managed K8s service and you don't have access to underlying the **infrastructure**.

**Autopilot GKE** does not allow you to use the **Hostpath** method or **mount** the folder with written permission.

You are only allowed to perform the read operation.

**HostPort** and **hostNetwork** are not permitted because node management is handled by GKE. Using hostPath volumes in write mode is prohibited while using hostPath volumes in read mode is allowed only for `/var/log/` path prefixes.

Read more at : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview

Comment: This is the correct answer, additionally, Autopilot does not use docker; it uses COS containerd nodes.  But you cannot deploy privileged pods in any case as indicated in the answer above.

Comment: thanks, Gari Singh, for the correction part of containerD. Noted.